# Outlook email send batch file with arguments (switch parameters)

Tags: email, batch-file, outlook, switch-statement

In email I can send

```
\\amsdev\ams\sub_applications\blueline\icons\blueline_launchmonitor.bat
```

However, I NEED to be able to send that batch file with switch or parameters
so it looks like this:

```
\\amsdev\ams\sub_applications\blueline\icons\blueline_launchmonitor.bat -server omsdev -cfg_region dev -blueline 540 -no_desktop_communication
```

I get error:

```
"We can't find \\......  .bat -server..... Please make sure your's using the correct location or web address.
```

What are my options?

Comment: What are you trying to send -- the batch file, or a hyper-link to such??

Comment: In email a person can click on the first network drive to the batch file and it works fine.   \\......\..monitor.bat  ,   however I have arguments that I NEED to be able to pass to it like  -server  and -cfg  etc..   but I cannot seem to find a way to encode or encapsulate this or some decent workaround.

Comment: What about a wrapper batch file which calls your batch file and passes over the arguments?

Comment: How would that work?  Can you explain?

Comment: I mean a batch file (`wrapper.bat`, placed in the same location as your file `blueline_launchmonitor.bat`); this contains your above command line like `call blueline_launchmonitor.bat -server ...` (without the preceding UNC path), including all arguments; in the e-mail, you refer to `wrapper.bat`.

Comment: I you could put together a viable answer instead of a comment to which it is easier to then work with then that would be more helpful.  thx

Comment: I would if I understood exactly what you want: 1) where is your batch file (attached to e-mail, somewhere else)? 2) what is in the e-mail (hyperlink to batch file, shortcut file,...)? 3) are all the arguments to be passed to the batch file static, or do they have to be assembled dynamically? thanks...

Comment: 1. batch file is on a network drive   \\mydrive\path\whatever.bat   2. the email is simply for the internal users getting the email that have access to the network drive and batch file to be able to have it launch and run the commands in the batch file   3.  arguments will be dynamic in which really the email will be automated with different argument values based on conditions ,   thx

Comment: Due to 3. (dynamic arguments), the wrapper approach is not possible, unfortunately... sorry...

Comment: This kind of thing could be used nefariously.